Replace 2-way switch with switch/outlet combo
I have a light switch that operates a single light on ceiling. There is another light switch that also operates the ceiling light. I want to replace one of them with a switch/outlet combo. The current switch has black wire, red wire, white wire and ground wire. Both the black and red are “hot”. The switch outlet combo i want to connect has 2 black screws and ground screw on one side. The other side has a brass screw and a silver screw. How do i connect that t wiring described?

You probably can't, not easily. A 3-way switch (that's each of the switches where two switches control one light) has two travelers + a common wire (which can be hot or switched hot). It does not have neutral, and you need neutral for a receptacle.

do you want a switched outlet or permanent

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact when you say it does not have a neutral, i DO have a white neutral line is attached to existing switch.

@DIY75 “switched” meaning this new switch/outlet combo, would operate the light along with the other switch? It does not have to.  To be honest I don’t really need the switch at all. Really just want an outlet where the switch is

Neutral is always white, but white is not always neutral. You don't have neutral on that switch, you have white being used for something else.

While not the source of the "not enough wires" problem, a key problem with figuring it out is that most US homes are wired with cables instead of individual wires. And those cables mostly come in two flavors:

Black/White/bare ground - a.k.a., /2 (because ground is everywhere and ignored for the count)
Black/Red/White/bare ground - a.k.a., /3

and get used for all kinds of things, including:
/2

120V black hot/white neutral
240V black hot/white hot - e.g., water heater
120V black switched hot/white hot - switch loop

/3

120V black hot/red switched hot/white neutral
240V/120V black hot/red hot/white neutral - e.g., oven or clothes dryer
120V - two of three colors traveler, one color hot, switched hot or neutral (but if it is neutral then it must be white) - this is the 3-way switch problem as being discussed here

Which means that:

Neutral is always white, but white is not always neutral
Three-way switches can be wired many different ways, and they don't always have neutral in each switch box (sometimes not in either box!)
Regular switches can be wired in a way (old-style switch loop) that does not have neutral in the switch box

When a white wire is used for something other than neutral, it is supposed to be marked with black or red or some other color (besides green) to indicate that it isn't neutral. But sometimes that is not done or the marking fades or (if tape) falls off.
In a different world, cables would come in multiple color configurations to match the usage. But that doesn't happen today because stocking extra cable types is expensive for an electrician (more money tied up in more types of cable, plus more space on the truck) and code allows for standard /2 and /3 to be used for "everything". The inexpensive alternative is to mark every single wire if it is not being used in the "native" color mode:

Hot - black
Neutral - white
Switched Hot - red
Travelers - yellow

However, code doesn't require that. It just requires:

Neutral - white (and must be native white, not marked)
Everything else (except ground) - any other color (except green)

To turn a 3-way switch location into a receptacle (or possibly a switch and a receptacle), you can do one of three things:

Find a switch box that has neutral and hot available. This often happens with one, but normally not both, of the 3-way switch boxes. But sometimes neither box has both hot and neutral.
Install new cables or wires as needed.
Install smart switches.

The last one is the new go-to solution. But even that is tricky, because what you typically need is one smart switch that acts as a remote for another smart switch without using up an extra wire for the signal, and the other smart switch has to either go in a box with neutral available or be usable without neutral (some are, some are not). But generally it is possible with the right type of smart switches to:

Replace a switch that has hot/traveler/traveler with a smart switch that then has hot/switched hot/neutral
Replace a switch that has switched hot/traveler/traveler with a smart switch "remote" that uses hot and neutral for power but doesn't connect to the switched hot

The specifics vary a lot depending on your particular existing 3-way switch configuration.
And finally, keep in mind that there are a number of situations where you must have either a switched light or a light that is always on for safety, which might mean you can't actually remove a switch but have to keep it around, even if it becomes a smart switch remote.

If the switch is not in a legally required location then it might be possible to eliminate the switch.  However, this involves re-wiring the other switch and possibly the light itself.
Another option would be to run one or two new cables to the switch box.
But the answer to the original question:  If there are only 4 wires and they are all connected to the 3-way switch then you don't have enough wires installed to both add a receptacle and keep the 3-way arrangement.

OK, thank you both. After fucking around with it for a couple hours, I figured that was the case, but I thought I would check since I’m no electrician. And now the original switch is not even working when I put it back. Good times.Time for professional. Thanks again.
